# получаю ошибку 403 при запросе к API геокодера

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Отправляю самый простой запрос для теста и получаю ошибку 403. В чем может быть проблема?
Ключ активный. Запрос взял из документации(((
Пример запроса:
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=4591e1e5-e1b7-447b-b3de-fedbe477564c&geocode=25.197300,55.274243&format=json

Comment: не забудьте прямо сейчас опубликованный вами apikey удалить.

Comment: ваше утверждение что ключ активный и то что в ответ сообщает `invalid key` как-то не сходится

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin смысла особого нет. в истории правок все видно. Ключ надо обновить теперь.

Comment: @teran, естественно, я подразумевал сервер (где и хранится apikey), а не данный сайт. жаль, что плохо сформулировал.

Comment: возможно это решит проблему сразу :D

Comment: @aleksandr-barakin уже изменил

Comment: @teran в том и вопрос, что в ЛК я вижу активный ключ, а получаю ошибку.
Ключ нужно активировать?
Как проверить действия ключа в ЛК?

Answer (score 0):

Андрей!

В указанном вами запросе указан API-ключ от другого сервиса. Для работы с сервисом Геокодера используйте ключ **JavaScript API и HTTP Геокодера**.

Кроме того, мы рекомендуем не публиковать ваши API-ключи, чтобы другие пользователи не могли использовать их.